# Wrong charset when mounting NFS share on OpenBSD

Tags: nfs, openbsd

I have a NFS server running on a Fedora 29 machine and other machines on my network (an Ubuntu box and a Debian VM) mount it properly.

But when I mount it on an OpenBSD VM, the charset is wrong, for example:

```
openBSD# ls -la a*o
-rw-rw-r--  1 renan  renan  0 Mar  4  2019 a????o
```

The `????` should be 'çã' (the file name is `ação`).

My command line on the OpenBSD was `mount -o tcp -t nfs 192.168.1.7:/mnt/data /mnt/data`.

What to do? I went through `mount`'s man page and there is no way to set the charset to use, apparently.

Comment: Have you changed it to a BR locale?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro setting the locale to a pt_BR one worked. I will write a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the locale manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/locale.1):

> Programs in the OpenBSD base system ignore the locale except for the character encoding, and it is not recommended to use any of these variables except that the following non-default setting is supported as an option:
>
> export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

Then, setting `LC_CTYPE` to be `pt_BR.UTF-8` works and I get the correct filenames now.

Comment: Excellent you pulled it off as I am not in OpenBSD anymore. +1. I *think* there was a "standard" place/file to define that.